# gem public_activity and custom activity for create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a simple form for a custom action

```
<%= form_for @book, :url => {:action => "list"} do |f| %>
<% end %>
```

The action in the controller looks like this at the moment:

```
@book = Book.new(book_params)
if @book.save
  @book.create_activity key: 'book.book_list', owner: current_user
  do something
else
  something else
end
```

This creates two new activities: One with activity key: book.create and one with the key: book.book_list.

Where do I set the custom activity for public_activity to prevent duplicate activities?

Comment: Adding `@book.activity key: 'book.book_list'` before the if solved this question. It created a one time value for the key. Next time activity.create is called the option is reset.

Answer (score 0):

If the Book model is "tracked", then it will create activity for create by default. This is why it creates two entries, one on @book.save and the other one for @book.create_activity.